# Tool in ArcMap for capturing ROIs of same size?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, classification, pixel

I'm trying to run supervised classifications and need all ROIs to be the same size. I'd like to capture the ROIs in ArcMap and so far can only find a tool which allows you to draw your ROIs by clicking and dragging to create polygons.

In ENVI and Erdas Imagine, there is a tool for capturing ROIs to ensure they are all the same size. For example if you want each ROI to be 9 pixels, when you're creating signature files, the cursor is 3x3 pixels. Then where you click on your raster, the 9 pixels are automatically captured without the need to draw a polygon. I can't remember what it's called as it's been a while since I used it.

After capturing the ROIs, I plan to export them as a tiff to use in EnMap

Does anyone know if such a tool exists in ArcMap?

Comment: If you need to also know about QGIS then I think that should be researched/asked as a separate question.

Comment: You can create points, convert them into raster and expand it by 1 to get 9 pixel group. Convert them to polygons

Comment: Have you tried the mask tool?  Also, as a workaround, create 9x9 pixel polygon; start editing; copy the polygon and paste where you need the clips.  I don't know of a tool in ArcGIS that can select pixels like you describe.

Comment: Thanks guys these both seem like viable options. Much appreciated